# Android App crashing in Cursor Query (Image/Video Cursor)

Tags: android, mediastore

My android app crashed at following line of code :

```
Cursor cursor= getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns,
                    selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);
```

Crash logs :

```
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window could not be created from binder.
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:133)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:41)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:681)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:679)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor.readFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:75)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:34)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:30)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:369)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
08-26 13:15:19.307  6992  6992 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
```

How can I avoid it ?

I suspect following code can be a reason for crash too

```
if (cursor!= null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Cursor is closed always.

any help appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Probably, your app is overflowing the memory limit. From [CursorWindowAllocationException](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/CursorWindowAllocationException.java): This exception is thrown when a CursorWindow couldn't be allocated, **most probably due to memory not being available.** You may want to narrow down your query scope.

Comment: is there any way-round you can suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one **trick**

```
Cursor cursor= getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns,
                    selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);

 if (cursor != null) {
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       ///// Put your idea here
   }
   cursor.close(); 
}
```